# Assigning variable based on position at a table with variable number of positions

Tags: python

I am begining in python hopefully my problem will not seem too obvious, I searched but could not find an answer. (I trimmed some of the text for clarity)

I have this text:

> Seat 1: AAA ($103.18) Seat 2: BBB ($97.50) Seat 3: CCC ($22.57) is
> dealer Seat 4: Sitout Seat 5: DDD ($104.74)

I am able to get the name and the number for every seat and know that dealer position = 3

I would like to assign position based on dealer position:

> SB = DDD BB = AAA Co = BBB B = CCC

my problem is that dealer position is not fixed, and the number of player is not fixed (it is between 2 and 10) and there can be some gaps(empty seats)

here is what I have done (which kind of work as it gives me strings in right order that i can then match) but I am pretty sure there is a way more elegant way to do it

```
Playerorder = [Seat1Name,Seat2Name,Seat3Name,Seat4Name,Seat5Name,Seat6Name,Seat7Name,Seat8Name,Seat9Name,Seat10Name]
Stacksord = [Seat1Stack,Seat2Stack,Seat3Stack,Seat4Stack,Seat5Stack,Seat6Stack,Seat7Stack,Seat8Stack,Seat9Stack,Seat10Stack]
PositionsPossibles = ["SB","BB","UTG","UTG1","UTG2","UTG3","LJ","HJ","CO","B"]
Positions = PositionsPossibles

#Emptycount count the number of empty seats I am deleteing in the string all #the empty seats, and empty positions
 
for i in range(Emptycount):
    del Positions[2]
       
Playerorder[:] = (value for value in Playerorder if value != "EMPTY")
 
Stacksord[:] = (value for value in Stacksord if value != "EMPTY")

 #then i reorder the relevant string based on button position   
PlayerinOrder =[]
for i in range(NumberOfPlayer):
    PlayerinOrder.append(Playerorder[(i+DealerSeat)%NumberOfPlayer])
print(PlayerinOrder)

StacksinOrder =[]
for i in range(NumberOfPlayer):
    StacksinOrder.append(Stacksord[(i+DealerSeat)%NumberOfPlayer])
print(StacksinOrder)
```

Comment: ok did not realise: PlayerOrder[AAA,BBB,CCC,"EMPTY,DDD,"EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY"]  Stack order [103.18,97.5,22.57,"EMPTY",104.74,"EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY"] 

basically there can be up to 10 player and we don t know which seat they are going to be seated. so I test player 1 to 10 to get the data and put "EMPTY" if I don t find it. What threw me off if that the number of player and the position are never fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample code is still missing a lot of variable contents. I couldn't copy/paste it to a script to test so I will try to guess what you're starting from and expecting out.

My guess is that you want positions to contain `['BB','CO','B','SB']` so that position codes match with the Playerorder `['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD']`.

To achieve this with simple code, you would need a list of the position codes that is organized in such a way that the values at negative and positive indexes correspond to the players sitting to the left and right of the dealer.

Here's an example:

```
DealerSeat = 2
relative   = ["B","SB","HJ","...","BB","CO"] # positions relative to dealer seat
positions  = [relative[i] for i,_ in enumerate(Playerorder,-DealerSeat)]

print(positions)   # ['BB',  'CO',  'B',   'SB']
print(Playerorder) # ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

In the `relative`  list, indexes -1,-2... correspond to players to the left of the dealer and indexes 0,1,2... correspond to the dealer himself and players on the right.

If you want to rotate the lists afterward so that the dealer is located at position zero, you can use subscripts like this:

```
PlayerinOrder = Playerorder[DealerSeat:]   + Playerorder[:DealerSeat]
StacksinOrder = StacksinOrder[DealerSeat:] + StacksinOrder[:DealerSeat]
positions     = positions[DealerSeat:]     + positions[:DealerSeat]

PlayerinOrder    # ['CCC', 'DDD',  'AAA',  'BBB']
StacksinOrder    # [22.57, 104.74, 103.18, 97.5]
positions        # ['B',   'SB',   'BB',   'CO']
```